# HTML Editor that can be used for tags' sanity check

Tags: html, tags

I am trying to use a text editor (without using an IDE e.g. eclise/IntelliJ) where I can analyse an HTML file e.g. which tags are unevenly used and also format HTML documents in a way that it picks up each tag and organises so that the document is more human-friendly.

I currently have notepad++ and Sumblime Text 2 on my machine. If there is any specific plugin that helps to do the job, could someone please advise?

** REASONING **

I have a messaging service that uses email templates and one of these has a bug somewhere. It's generating a misaligned (i.e. odd) tag which can be visible if I was to put it in some audit trail (gets picked up in a tabular view). I would like to use a text editor to check the buggy tag.

KR,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In notepad++ you can do that if your open and closing tags are below eachother for example

```
<div>
something here
</div>
```

but if you have it inline like this

`<div>something here</div>`

you cannot do much with it.
Is this what you are asking?

Also if you want the vertical tab lines to be visible click on the "show indent guide" in the top toolbar

Answer (score 1):

There are several online tools that can format the HTML for you. Do a quick Google search for "online html formatter" and try a couple out. Some will provide more options than others. Once formatted properly, it'll be human readable and probably be pretty easy to spot the stray tag.

Comment: Just found out that someone wrote some buggy code that is not escaping stuff properly....even then, the online tool would help me a lot in the future.